# Unable to start up mysql after database crash (Laravel Homestead)

Tags: mysql, linux, homestead

I was adding a new field to an existing database with about 7 million records already within it. This modification suddenly caused mysql to crash and I cannot figure out how to recover things.

I am running a Vagrant/Homestead setup on my local windows 10 machine.

I run "vagrant ssh" to connect to the virtual box.

Output from /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xeaf22b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x48b)[0x7794ab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f6eafeea890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7f6eaf1e6e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7f6eaf1e8801]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x74f996]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x66)[0x1086196]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18os_file_flush_funci+0x1e0)[0xf69e00]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16os_file_set_sizePKc13pfs_os_file_tmb+0x324)[0xf71314]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13SysTablespace8set_sizeER8Datafile+0x22b)[0x1156a8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13SysTablespace14open_or_createEbbPmS0_+0xcf)[0x115921f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x34c8)[0x1030628]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xef683d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x7cc69f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc888c5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x1e5)[0xc8bde5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x771770]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x795)[0x772e75]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f6eaf1c9b97]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x76921a]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-01-29T03:01:42.557756Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-01-29T03:01:42.558912Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 10980 ...
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564377Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564383Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564388Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564393Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564397Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564680Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-29T03:01:42.564803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-01-29T03:01:42.567749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-01-29T03:01:42.579265Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-29T03:01:42.580822Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-01-29T03:01:42.592142Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-01-29T03:01:42.593066Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 62908547934
2020-01-29T03:01:42.601807Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 62909011867
2020-01-29T03:01:42.601920Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-01-29T03:01:42.601926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-01-29T03:01:42.618100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
2020-01-29T03:01:42.625779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-01-29T03:01:42.738017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-29T03:01:42.738043Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-29T03:01:42.738085Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-29T03:01:42.748224Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: fsync() returned EIO, aborting.
2020-01-29 03:01:42 0x7fca264c1740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140506202642240 in file ut0ut.cc line 918
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
03:01:42 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

I attempted a reinstallation of mysql without any luck. The databases should still be there, but I am unsure if I am able to recover them now?

Comment: How much disk space is free?

Comment: I checked this. About 58% disk space is free (many GB) on the drive for mysql. I’m out atm so can’t show the output from du command but I know this wasn’t the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `innodb_force_recovery`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Comment: Additionally, you can refer to this https://serverfault.com/questions/592793/mysql-crashed-and-wont-start-up .. seems a lot similar to what you're facing.

Comment: I tried this setting but mysql won't start. The error log appears the same as above. I added:[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 3 - (to the /etc/my.cnf) file and tried sudo service mysql stop/start commands

Comment: I also tried bumping up the force recovery all the way to 6 and still won't start.

Comment: At this stage I believe the data may be lost. I will need to work with my backups and reinstall Vagrant/Homestead to try and get mysql working (I had attempted to remove the databases to see if mysql would load and this still didn't resolve the issue).